# I can not create react application there is an error saying

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarn-v2

D:\frontend\example>npx create react-app rcsg
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run

Comment: Please add more details about the full error or logs you have while running the command.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a `-` in `npx create react-app`

correct command is :

`npx create-react-app <project-folder-name>`

correct command to init your project named **rcsg**:

`npx create-react-app rcsg`